# Python - Folium layer control doesn't work?

Tags: python, dictionary, geometry, google-maps-markers, folium

Hope you can help me :)

I made a map with folium; different markers & folium circles.

Here is my code:

```
m = folium.Map(location=[52.099058, 5.096911], tiles="cartodbpositron", zoom_start=7)


for i in range(0,len(df_comp)):
   folium.Circle(
      location=[df_comp.iloc[i]['latitude'], df_comp.iloc[i]['longitude']],
      popup=df_comp.iloc[i][['Stad', 'm2']],
      radius=float(df_comp.iloc[i]['m2'])/30,
      color='yellow',
      fill=True,
      fill_color='yellow'
   ).add_to(m)

for index, location_info in gdf.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["latitude"], location_info["longitude"]], popup= location_info[['Naam','Volume']], icon=folium.Icon(color="blue", icon="glyphicon-wrench")).add_to(m)
    
for index, location_info in gdf2.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["latitude"], location_info["longitude"]], popup= location_info['Naam'], icon=folium.Icon(color="green", icon="glyphicon-retweet")).add_to(m)
    
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)


m
```

Everything works fine expect the layercontrol, it's visible but doesn't show the different markers / folium cir[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23vKq.png)cle. I want a layer control so i can select which kind of marker I see and the circle too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Since no geopandas data was presented, we created sample data and used that as a data frame, which was also appropriated for the geopandas data frame. Some modifications may be necessary, but I don't think any errors will occur. Layer control is possible by creating a layer for each and adding objects to that layer. Since you want the circle to be a layer object as well, I have created three layers. Finally, we add the layers we have created to the map.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_comp = pd.DataFrame({'latitude': np.random.uniform(51.8, 52.2, size=10),
                        'longitude': np.random.uniform(4.9, 5.1, size=10),
                        'm2': np.random.randint(100,1000,10),
                        'Naam': ['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BB', 'BC', 'BD', 'CC', 'CD', 'DD']})

import folium

m = folium.Map(location=[52.099058, 5.096911], tiles="cartodbpositron", zoom_start=10)

feature_gp1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name="circle")
feature_gp2 = folium.FeatureGroup(name="wrench")
feature_gp3 = folium.FeatureGroup(name="retweet")

for i, location_info in df_comp.iterrows():
    folium.Circle(
      location=[location_info['latitude'], location_info['longitude']],
      popup=location_info['m2'],
      radius=float(location_info['m2'])/3,
      color='orange',
      fill=True,
      fill_color='orange'
   ).add_to(feature_gp1)    

for index, location_info in df_comp.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["latitude"],
                   location_info["longitude"]],
                  popup= location_info[['Naam']],
                  icon=folium.Icon(color="blue", icon="glyphicon-wrench")).add_to(feature_gp2)
    
for index, location_info in df_comp.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([location_info["latitude"],
                   location_info["longitude"]],
                  popup= location_info['Naam'],
                  icon=folium.Icon(color="green", icon="glyphicon-retweet")).add_to(feature_gp3)

feature_gp1.add_to(m)
feature_gp2.add_to(m)
feature_gp3.add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much! Really great solution, really simple but very effective :)